# Regex works on Regexpal but not on Java

Tags: java, regex, vb6

**Note: I just learned Regex so it is likely to be a crappy pattern**

I hacked up this regex

```
Begin VB\.Label\s+([^\s]+)\s+.+\s+Caption\s+=\s*("([^"]+)")\s+.+\s+Index\s+=\s*([0-9]+)
```

to match these form controls in a VB6 .frm file

```
         Begin VB.Label lblError 
        AutoSize        =   -1  'True
        Caption         =   "Blah blah"
        Height          =   195
        Index           =   49
        Left            =   105
        TabIndex        =   31
        Top             =   3135
        Width           =   4455
     End
```

When I tested it on Regexpal, it worked fine
[image: regexpal]

but `matcher.find()` only finds completely garbage string

```
Error [&About] - "&About"
```

This is my escaped Java matcher

```
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("Begin VB\\.Label\\s+([^\\s]+)\\s+.+\\s+Caption\\s+=\\s+(\"([^\"]+)\")\\s+.+\\s+Index\\s+=\\s+([0-9]+)");
```

EDIT: This is what actually matches:

```
      Begin VB.Menu mnuHelp 
     Caption         =   "&About"
     Index           =   5
  End
```

Comment: I do a lot what you do with regexpal and java... for me it is 99% that I missed an escape character!

Comment: Can you post the string that actually matches? That might give some clues...

Comment: I've edited the post. A menu gets hooked instead of Labels. It's quite bizarre.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that it has something to do with the `.+` in your RegEx. Try:

`Begin VB\.Label lblError[0-9A-Za-z\-\'\s\=\"\&]+\sIndex\s+=\s+[0-9]+`

I tested it and it worked. [Demo Here](http://regexr.com?30v8v)

Comment: Worked great! I modified it slightly so I get the Caption and Index property.
`Begin VB\.Label lblError[0-9A-Za-z-'\s="&]+\sCaption\s+=\s+"([^"]+)"[0-9A-Za-z-'\s="&]+\sIndex\s+=\s+([0-9]+)`

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest going a different direction with your regex.  You're trying to parse out specific labels in your input, and then pull certain values from within that label.

It's tempting to try to do it all in one master regex, but those kind of regex's can be difficult to parse and very inflexible.

I would suggest doing this in two parts:

1. Pull out the label contents.
2. Pull out the specific properties out of the single label.

This would mean something like the following:

```
/* A pattern to grab the entire label -- Everything from Begin to End */
Pattern pEntireLabel = Pattern.compile("Begin VB\.Label.*?End", Pattern.MULTILINE);

/* Patterns for each specific value you want. */
Pattern pCaption = Pattern.compile("Caption\s*=\s*(\S*)");
/* . . . etc. for each value you want.  . . . */

Matcher mEntireLabel = pEntireLabel.matcher(...);
while (mEntireLabel.find()) {
  String label = mEntireLabel.group(0);

  /* Now find the specific parameters inside the label */
  Matcher mCaption = pCaption.matcher(label);
  if (mCaption.find()) {
       caption = mCaption.group(1);
  }

  /* Reapply this same logic for each property you want. */

}
```

The advantage here is that this is more adaptable -- if you need to get a new parameter, it's easy to just add it in.  If you no longer need one, you take that out.  If the formatting within label might have part of a value missing, then you won't get that one parameter but you'll get the rest, rather than the whole regex failing.  Etc., Etc.

Comment: This solves another problem I encountered when trying to break my regex up- finding a pattern that corresponded to only that label. Matching within the overall match is a good approach, thank you.